# Find the global maximum of $2\sin\left(x\right)-\cos\left(2x\right)$

Tags: calculus

I found local maximum and minimum of function $2\sin\left(x\right)-\cos\left(2x\right)$, but I don't know how to find global maximum.

Answer (score 3):

You can write the following using $\cos(2x) = 1-2\sin^2(x)$
$$f(x) = 2\sin( x) - \cos (2x) = 2 \sin(x) + 2\sin^2(x) -1 \\= 2(\sin(x) +\tfrac{1}{2})^2 - \tfrac{3}{2}$$

From here note that the square term is always positive, maximum occurs at $\sin(x) = 1$ and minimum at $\sin(x) = \tfrac{-1}{2}$.

Thus *maximum* $= 3$ and *minimum* = $\tfrac{-3}{2}$.

Comment: Yes, I found them too, but when I drew graph online, there is global max at -1 and I don't know how to calculate that.

Comment: @jakob. The square term, think how you can maximise it?